# Separating data in a column by grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a multiple column dataframe and want to separate data in a particular column by grouping them based on another column.

Here is an example:

```
ID     Name   Score
1      John   100
2      Lisa   80
3      David  75 
4      Lisa   92
5      John   89
6      Lisa   72
```

I would like my output to be like:

```
index  John  Lisa  David
0      100   80    75
1      89    92    NaN
2      NaN   72    NaN
```

I understand I can easily use the code:

`df[df['Name'] == 'John]]` and separate all the scores that John has in the dataframe, but since my dataframe is very large I would like to have a clean output like what I showed here.

Comment: Looks like a simple pivot (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). You can generate the index needed to pivot grouping the dataframe by `Name` and taking the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
ix = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
pd.pivot_table(df,'Score', ix, 'Name')

Name  David   John  Lisa
1      75.0  100.0  80.0
2       NaN   89.0  92.0
3       NaN    NaN  72.0
```

Comment: Surprisingly for smaller DataFrames (a few thousand rows) `df.groupby('Name').Score.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T` is faster.

Comment: Wouldn't have said that piece of code works faster. Interesting to know :-)